# How to change laravel notification user model receiver?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-notification

We have an API which connects to our own first party applications. Our API is sending out notifications based on user actions or if there is an update to the application etc.

Our `API` is modular structured.

### Example

Our `user model` in API is located in `App\Modules\Accounts\Models\User`. Each month we send an invoice database notification to user from our API. In database it adds the notification and the `notifiable_type` is `App\Modules\Accounts\Models\User`.

[image]

But in our user application the `user model` is located in `App\Modules\User` which results user having 0 notifications.

### Question

I know I can move the `user model` to exactly the same path in the user application but it seems somewhat wrong. Is there a way to tell the `user model` in our `user application` where to receive database notification on? Something like:

```
public function(){
    return $this->receivesNotificationsFrom('App\Modules\Accounts\Models\User');
}
```

Comment: Not as an default. Do i understand you correct: Your API writes this into your database (table `notifications` right?) and the only consumer is your app?

Comment: @Paladin as of now, yes!

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this in api as like this (suggesting, i would also use your namespace for users like you did, what i would never do, but lets suggest it). There are several ways to test, what is the best solution for you.

I would:

1. In your consuming app, you create a new model `App\Modules\Accounts\Models\User` that just extends your existing `User` class. I would test, if i can get to goal with this approach.
2. You create an artisan command to just rename the classes in your `notification` table and let this run by laravel's scheduler, so in your `notifications` table are the correct namespaces for your app.
3. This all "feels" wrong and i would never break with the defaults of `App\User`, because you run into traps like this and end up with "messy" solutions like 1 or 2.

Sry, i have no better ideas now, but maybe, it gives you some little inspirations

Comment: Well if you are going to use modular structure then there is no other way to accomplish this